# Object Oriented Programming / get minimum/maximum in java... im a newbie

Tags: java

I already got the average and my program is already reading three integer numbers from the user, my problem is I have no idea how to get the maximum and minimum numbers of my program :(

-Im new to programming :(

Here's my program :

Main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestNumbers {

    public static void main (String[]args){    

    int n1, n2, n3;
    System.out.println("Enter three integer numbers ");

          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

          n1 = in.nextInt();
          n2 = in.nextInt();
          n3 = in.nextInt();      

    Numbers num=new Numbers();
    num.setNum(n1, n2, n3);

    System.out.println("The Maximum of : "+n1+ " , " +n2+ " , " +n3+ " is ");
    System.out.println("The Minimum of : "+n1+ " , " +n2+ " , " +n3+ " is ");
    System.out.println("The Average of : "+n1+ " , " +n2+ " , " +n3+ " is "+num.getAve());
    System.out.println("Press any key to continue...");      
    }
}
```

base class :

```
public class Numbers {
    private int n1;
    private int n2;
    private int n3;
    private int ave;


    public void setNum(int n1, int n2, int n3){
        this.n1=n1;
        this.n2=n2;
        this.n3=n3;
    }

    public double getAve(){
        ave=(n1+n2+n3)/3;
        return ave;
    }

}
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: This is not the place to ask this question. It is likely that it'll get closed for being too localized. You may rephrase it so it can be more general and you may get upvotes instead the other way around.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), it contains lots of helper methods for all kinds of mathematical operations. (@StephenC better like this? :P )

Comment: Your average is wrong. `ave` is an `int`, you are trying to divide it by 3 and then return a `double`. Now your turn to guess (just check it out on google, shouldn't be hard to find) why this is not working

Comment: @Veger - yes.  Much better.  (Sorry to jump on you ... but I think it is important to consider the context when answering questions like this.)

Comment: yehaay my program is now working thanks a lot ""sir's""

Answer (score 8):

I will give you a simple algorithm.
Compare your first number and second number.Find maximum of two and compare it with third number.
Now can you do the coding?

Comment: +1 - This is the best answer.  @NEWBIE you will learn more if you figure out what this Answer is saying, and do the work of coding it for yourself.

Comment: well thankx,, I figure it out
but please,, after you guys put a negative vote can u check this if this is the right solution? im really new to programming

public double getMin(){
   return Math.min(n1, Math.min(n2, n3));
}

public double getMax(){
   return Math.max(n1, Math.min(n2, n3));
}

I run it and its okay but im not sure

Comment: No it is wrong. Anyway, probably you don't want to use `Math.min` or `Math.max`, try to write your own algorithm so you can learn more. Java is very powerful, but if you want to learn programming you should start from the basics

Comment: why wrong? it works perfectly fine

Comment: @NEWBIE...Since you are new to programming, I suggest coding the algorithms rather than using standard libraries.If you want to become a good programmer,you should know how these standard libraries are working internally, atleast for some simple functions.Always remember that learing a language is very easy task, but developing an elegant algorithm for a problem makes you a good programmer

Comment: yeah im wrong.. the maximum output is wrong.. why?

Comment: @NEWBIE..show us the code

Comment: public int getMin(){
   return Math.min(n1, Math.min(n2, n3));
}

public int getMax(){
   return Math.max(n2, Math.min(n2, n3));
}

Comment: public int getMax(){ return Math.max(n2, Math.max(n2, n3)); }

Comment: still error.. I tried 1, 2, 3 it works and now I tried 3, 2, 1 output is 2 >.<

Comment: oh nevermind sir I get it,, I change Math.max(n2, n3) to Math.max(n1,n3) and it works yay... my program is now complete thanks a lot guys and for those also who give me lecture,, sorry

Answer (score 1):

(n1+n2+n3)/3.0

```
public double getAve(){
   ave=(n1+n2+n3)/3;
   return ave;
}
```

This function worries me because ave is an integer and the function should return a double. You will lose precision with the ints you are using for your calculation. Consider casting.

```
public double getAve(){
   double result = (double)(n1+n2+n3)/3.0
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Your cast is in the wrong place. This only works because you divide an `int` with a `double`. It should be either `(n1+n2+n3)/3.0` (d is not needed, 3.0 is a double already) or `((double)(n1+n2+n3))/3`